# Кроссбраузерный способ сделать картинки серыми?

Tags: html, css

Кроссбраузерный способ сделать картинки серыми, а при наведении вернуть им цвета
в css  выставил, но нужна поддержка, начиная с IE9

```
filter: grayscale(1);
```

Comment: [Cross-Browser CSS Grayscale](https://gist.github.com/karlhorky/3478370)

Comment: то что @exvayn показал по ссылке ищется поиском за 20 секунд, если посмотрите мою историю то увидите что этот вопрос я задавал примерно где то 2 или 3 года назад , самый кроссбраузерный вариант это применять два изображения а при событиях hover или на js подменять ...

Comment: Я бы не писал тут, если это ищется за 20 секунд. То что скинули, в обсуждениях написали что на ie поддержки нет https://caniuse.com/#search=filter
Вы предлагаете мне искать в сотнях ваших вопросах нужное? логичнее скинуть сюда

Comment: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/grayscale-image-web/ , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813142/internet-explorer-10-howto-apply-grayscale-filter. Могу только ссылки кидать.. :) Нет личного опыта.

Comment: я же написал что самое кроссбраузерное это `использование двух изображений`  а filter хоть на js это всё grayscale

Comment: "нравится" наставили а там svg но в IE меньше 10 не поддерживается, а в том примере с github именно filter на svg  + webkit

Comment: наставил нравится, потому что - нравится. ведь действительно полезный коммент, в отличии от некоторых заумных и бесполезно обобщенных + для ie 10 в других проектах может помочь